# Spring Boot trouble with external resource

Tags: spring-boot, resources

Trying to load static resources from outside of app, but i'm stuck:
Having registerd my resource location like:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("file:///C:/opt/files/");
```

My sample image which i want to load is under c:\opt\files\ stored.
In my HTML page i tried to load these image like:

```
<img src="sample_image.jpg" />
```

But without luck. In my understanding is it only necessary to give the resourne name to "src" and the resource handler will have a look into the given path of file:///C:/opt/files/ and load the resource.

Where im wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. The registering of resources like in the question is correct. It wasn't work because i had trouble with my WebSecurityConfiguration that did noct accept the matcher of the resource.